# Calling AsyncStorage as component loads

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-effect, asyncstorage

I'm trying to load an object with AsyncStorage in React Native as a component loads, but useEffect creates an infitine loop and every other question I find about this says to use componentWillMount, which appears to be not working anymore. I'm trying to call puxaGastos() when component renders so I can pass that to a FlatList but don't know how to call it

```
const [gastos, setGastos] = useState()
const puxaGastos = async () => {
    const gastosGuardados = await AsyncStorage.getItem('transacao')
    const gastosParse = JSON.parse(gastosGuardados)
    setGastos(gastosParse)
    console.log(gastos)
}
return (<View style={styles.tela}><FlatList/></View>)
```

Comment: Please show the rest of the code too, where's the useEffect causing the infinite load.

Answer (score 0):

- Option 1: Use `useCallback` to wrap `puxaGastos` to prevent recursively re-render and call it in `useEffect` with dependencies contain puxaGastos `[puxaGastos]`

```js
const [gastos, setGastos] = useState()
const puxaGastos =useCallback(async () => {
    const gastosGuardados = await AsyncStorage.getItem('transacao')
    const gastosParse = JSON.parse(gastosGuardados)
    setGastos(gastosParse)
    console.log(gastos)
},[])
useEffect(() =>{
  puxaGastos()
},[puxaGastos])
return (<View style={styles.tela}><FlatList/></View>)
```

- Option 2 define and call `puxaGastos` inside `useEffect` with dependencies includes puxaGastos

```js
const [gastos, setGastos] = useState()
useEffect(() =>{
  const puxaGastos =async () => {
        const gastosGuardados = await AsyncStorage.getItem('transacao')
        const gastosParse = JSON.parse(gastosGuardados)
        setGastos(gastosParse)
        console.log(gastos)
    }
  puxaGastos()
},[puxaGastos])
return (<View style={styles.tela}><FlatList/></View>)
```

Answer (score 0):

With [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md), you can access AsyncStroage synchronously after the initialization is completed, which may be a good way.

```
  import { XStorage } from 'react-native-easy-app';
  import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

   export const RNStorage = {
       token: undefined, 
       isShow: undefined, 
       userInfo: undefined
   };

  const initCallback = () => {

       // From now on, you can write or read the variables in RNStorage synchronously

       // equal to [console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem('isShow'))]
       console.log(RNStorage.isShow); 

       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('token',TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3==') ]
       RNStorage.token = 'TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3=='; 

       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('userInfo',JSON.stringify({ name:'rufeng', age:30})) ]
       RNStorage.userInfo = {name: 'rufeng', age: 30}; 
  };

  XStorage.initStorage(RNStorage, AsyncStorage, initCallback);
```